# Is there a way to evolve a kadabra to an Alakazam and Onix to Steelix in Silver virtual console without pokebank or pokemon transporter?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I don't have another silver virtual console or gold and so I need to know if i can get alakazam an steelix in silver for the virtual console.

Comment: Seeing how there is no Pokebank in the original Gold/Silver, the only want to obtain them (legitimately) is through trading them with another virtual console

Comment: Not sure why the OPs question has been marked down so much.  Seems like a perfectly fine question to me?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other way.

The only way to evolve Pokémon that evolve by trade is to trade them. The only way to trade in Gold and Silver on virtual console is to another Gold or Silver game on virtual console.